# Import Error in Hadoop Mapreduce in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, jar, mapreduce

I was trying to compile some Hadoop 2.3.0 mapreduce jobs in Eclipse. I imported the following jars

```
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.3.0.jar
commons-cli-1.2.jar
hadoop-common-2.3.0.jar
```

However whenever I import the org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper I get the following error

```
 The class file Mapper<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT> contains a signature '(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/
     Mapper<TKEYIN;TVALUEIN;TKEYOUT;TVALUEOUT;>.Context;)V' ill-formed at position 74
```

I can't find any error like this online, so I wonder what it might be.

Comment: Looks like you may have a typo in your code. What is Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce?

Comment: Yeah but that code is not mine, it's from the release.

Comment: Post the code from line 60 - 80

Comment: I looked at my eclpise config and remember having to bring maven and a couple other jars into eclipse. Have you looked at this Cloudera blog http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/05/how-to-configure-eclipse-for-hadoop-contributions/

Comment: I think I found a fix, an option to load JRE 5 appeared and when I did it all the errors disappeared, weird.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue.  My project was first created to use JRE1.5 compliance.   Switching to 1.8 with a proper JDK in the classpath and doing a clean build solved this issue.

Comment: How to fix switch JDK to 1.8 and build ?